# No logro hacer click en el boton

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Estoy usando selenium en python para extraer el codigo de esta pagina web: https://es.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/ . Necesito hacer click en '1 minuto', '5 minutos', '15 minutos'... y no se como hacerlo. Necesito ayuda, no se porque me da error al ejecutar el codigo:

```py
def extractor_de_acciones(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    nombre = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tv-symbol-header__first-line"]').text
    precio = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"]').text
    fecha = datetime.now()
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tab-R450LabG tab-3I2ohC86 noBorder-3I2ohC86"]')
    button.click()
extractor_de_acciones('https://es.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/')
```

pd: lo raro es que en el codigo fuente de la pagina no aparece ninguna etiqueta tipo button pero si que hay botones en la pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Holas, por lo que vi es un error por obstrucción, el cartelito de las cookies que sale es el que causa el error, cuando selenium va a hacer click el cartel esta en medio y por eso genera un error, la solución es poner una espera o hacer click en el boton de aceptar o sino hacer scroll para abajo capas, yo opte por la opción de cerrar el cartel ni bien aparezca.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def extractor_de_acciones(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    nombre = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tv-symbol-header__first-line"]').text
    precio = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"]').text
    fecha = datetime.now()
    # espera hasta que aparezca el boton y cuando aparece hace click en aceptar asi no genera el error
    btnWait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class="button-1iktpaT1 size-s-3mait84m intent-primary-1-IOYcbg appearance-default-dMjF_2Hu"]'))).click()
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tab-R450LabG tab-3I2ohC86 noBorder-3I2ohC86"]')
    button.click()

extractor_de_acciones('https://es.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/')
```

Yo ahí puse un selector por css que me parece que es mas dinamico, pero igual vos lo podes cambiar a gusto, tipo por un xpath o demas

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono!!!